# Глядеть и смотреть

Tags: этимология, стилистика

С одной стороны, слова "глядеть" и "смотреть" - синонимы. Но с другой - я интуитивно чувствую в них разные оттенки смысла, но, честно говоря, не могу их сформулировать. Может, кто-нибудь мне поможет?
И еще, интересно было бы узнать происхождения слова "смотреть". С "глядением" понятно - от слова "взгляд". А вот "смотреть" от какого слова произошло?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Смотреть* – совсем нейтральное, а *глядеть* – больше разговорное.

Кроме того, у этих глаголов, а также у слов, образованных от них, иногда сочетаемость разная. Иногда они взаимозаменяемые, а иногда и совсем нет. Например, "смотреть фильм, спектакль" (а не "глядеть"). Или производный предлог "несмотря на".

Answer (score 1):

Я ответил бы таким образом.

"Глядеть" - бесцельно, как процесс.

"Смотреть" - целенаправленно, для анализа ситуации. "Гляжу в озёра синие, В садах ромашки рву...", "Я за реченьку гляжу В голубую даль. Никому не расскажу Про свою печаль", "Я на солнышке сижу И на солнышко гляжу, Всё сижу и сижу И на солнышко гляжу".

Но: "Смотрю я на тебя и диву даюсь: ну до чего ж ты бестолковый!", "смотровые окна", "смотр художественной самодеятельности", "Если посмотреть направо, вы увидите тульский кремль...". "Переходя дорогу, посмотрите налево, затем - направо". Правда,  иногда зоны их применения пересекаются. "Посмотрю я на быструю речку" - "Погляжу я на быструю речку". Здесь применение того или иного глагола зависит от выбора автора: "музыкант" поставит "погляжу" (звучнее текст) - и от содержания последующего текста...

Если согласитесь со мною, потому что ответ выдан по интуиции, без опоры на авторитеты.

Answer (score 1):

В. Даль хорошо дает направление исходной мысли. У него: глядеть — направить взгляд, при этом можно ничего не воспринимать (как бы "таращиться гляделками"). У него же: смотреть — глядеть со смыслом (направить взгляд и "считать информацию").

Answer (score 0):

Это все еще раз подтверждает тот факт, что "смотреть" – слово нейтральное, а "глядеть" –  разговорное.

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, что  глядят ВО что-то - в даль, в небо, в озеро, в душу, в лес, в книгу в телевизор и т. д., а смотрят НА что-то - на картину, на экран, на дом, на машину, на страницу и т. д.

Comment: Странно Вам кажется. Миллионы людей говорят "смотреть в глаза", "смотреть в окно", "глядеть на дорогу", "глядеть на костёр" и т.п. Это всё есть и в словарях, и в хороших книгах — читайте, слушайте.

Comment: на страницу и.д.?

Comment: Миллионы людей звОнят, ложат, читают катАлоги и т.д. То, что делают миллионы, никак не доказывает моей неправоты. Я не претендую на звание истины в последней инстанции. Считается, что одинаково правильно говорить и творОг, и твОрог, но если учесть, что образованные от этого существительного прилагательное имеет ударение на второй слог, для меня лично, логичнее произносить творОг. Что же касается смотреть в глаза или в окно  - так в русском языке много исключений) еще смотрят в бинокль, во что-то заглядывают, за чем-то присматривают и т.д.